# Is there a way to get the FK column value from Doctrine 2.2 entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, associations

I've been wondering about the subj lately. Of course, I could always create a custom query that selects IDENTITY(entity.associated_entity). I'm just wondering if I could do the same without such additional step. And joins.
**EDIT:** and, of course, without the perversion of declaring the FK column among the entity's fields.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Cant promise this actually is the designated way to solve this problem.

What I did is to add another explicit definition for the FK column.

```
/**
 * @Column(type="integer", length=11, nullable=false)
 */
protected $fktable_id;
```

Even if this might be a perversion :) whole Doctrine is

Comment: This will surely work for retrieving the foreign key from the entity after it's just been loaded from the DB, but I'm almost sure that if somewhere later in the code we change the association in a standard way, this field won't be updated. Which will lead to more crutches. Espescially if we want to use such entity in several methods.